# Laravel DB query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am building my first db query in laravel4 but I am having some trouble.

My objective is to show site alerts to users once they login.   I am getting an error that says: "trying to get property of a non-object"

My model:

```
class SiteAlert extends Eloquent  {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'sitealerts';


public function scopegetSiteAlerts() {

    $alert = DB::table('sitealerts')
            ->where('isActive', '=', '1')
            ->select('isActive', 'alertTitle', 'alertText', 'alertDate', 'created_at',
                'alertStart', 'alertExpires')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
            return $alert;


}


}
```

My Controller (note:  this is my user controller, I don't have a separate controller for my alerts)

```
public function getdashboard($id)
    {

        //

        $alert = SiteAlert::getSiteAlerts();
        $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
        return View::make('contractors.dashboard')
            ->with('contractor', $contractor)
            ->with('alert', $alert);
    }
```

And my view file (dashboard.blade.php)

```
     @if (isset($alert))
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <img alt="Client logo" src="../assets/images/logo.png" class="avatar" />
        <p class="lead">Howdy, {{$contractor->contact_name; }}</p>
        <p>
            Welcome to your ContractorSherpa Dashboard.<br />
            Your account allows you to view information relating to your projects. You can keep up on progress,
            upload files, make new payments / print receipts, view previous payments, &amp; more.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        @while ($alert)
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> {{$alert->alertTitle}}
                        <span class="floatRight">
                            {{$alert->alertDate}}
                        </span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{$alert->alertText}}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endwhile
    </div>
</div>
@else
<img alt="Client logo" src="../assets/images/logo.png"  class="avatar" />
<p class="lead">Howdy, {{$contractor->contact_name; }}</p>
<p>
    Welcome to your ContractorSherpa Dashboard.<br />
    Your account allows you to view information relating to your projects. You can keep up on progress,
    upload files, make new payments / print receipts, view previous payments, &amp; more.
</p>
@endif
```

My guess is that I haven't setup the controller correctly to be able to access the $alert.

Any help would be appreciated.  TIA

Comment: which line triggers an error?

Comment: @edvinas.me  The   <i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> {{$alert->alertTitle}}  line triggers the error

Comment: `@while ($alert)` how is this not always true?

Comment: it is because `$alert` is empty. You cannot call `->alertTitle` on empty `$alert`.

Comment: You can do `dd($alert);` in your view to see what it returns. Then you'll know how to handle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because in your Views you treat variables as objects, when they are passed as an array. Generally, you shuoldn't access Models in your Views, you should have all the logic in Controller (as you do) and then pass data to view with `->with()` as an array.

**Updated**

The problem might be in `@while($alert)`, replace it with this:

```
                       @foreach ($alert as $a)
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> {{$a->alertTitle}}
                        <span class="floatRight">
                            {{$a->alertDate}}
                        </span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{$a->alertText}}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Actually you are wrong. If you notice, he is using command get(), and that command returns data as object

Comment: @Alen I have indeed missed that, the comment regarding the use ofmodels in views still applies though. Answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

One of your passed objects seems to be empty. Are your sure that there are data in your database for the given id?

Comment: I thought that might be the case too, but the database does have data in it.  All rows have a value.

Comment: you are passing a colletion of alert-objects into the view. You have to iterate over each element of these collection... use a foreach-construct

Answer (score 0):

The problems here are:

```
// this returns array of stdObjects
$alerts = DB::table('sitealerts')
        ->where('isActive', '=', '1')
        ->select('isActive', 'alertTitle', 'alertText', 'alertDate', 'created_at',
            'alertStart', 'alertExpires')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
        return $alerts;

// then in your view you try to get property of array so replace:
@while($alert)
// with:
@foreach ($alerts as $alert) // in your controller use with('alerts',$alerts);
```